# /run/user/1000/gvfs Permission Denied

Tags: gvfs

`# ls -l /run/user/1000`

Gives the following:

```
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 at-spi
srw-rw-rw- 1 mtc mtc   0 feb  5 20:50 bus
drwx------ 3 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 dbus-1
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 dconf
d????????? ? ?   ?     ?            ? doc
drwx--x--x 2 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 gdm
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc 140 feb  5 20:50 gnupg
d????????? ? ?   ?     ?            ? gvfs
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc  40 feb  5 20:50 gvfsd
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 keyring
srw-rw-rw- 1 mtc mtc   0 feb  5 20:50 pipewire-0
-rw-rw---- 1 mtc mtc   0 feb  5 20:50 pipewire-0.lock
srw-rw-rw- 1 mtc mtc   0 feb  5 20:50 pk-debconf-socket
drwx------ 2 mtc mtc  80 feb  5 20:50 pulse
drwxr-xr-x 2 mtc mtc  60 feb  5 20:50 speech-dispatcher
drwxr-xr-x 6 mtc mtc 160 feb  5 20:50 systemd
```

And whatever operation I try to do on gvfs I get a `Permission denied` error (including simple ls).

My final goal is to access to my android phone connected via usb, but what does this "????" means for `gvfs` directory?

(At the time of above `ls` no phone device is connected)

Comment: Try again without root/sudo.

Comment: @DanielT it's not about the user, which clearly was root, it is about the permission in status '?'.

Comment: You can't access FUSE-mounted filesystems like doc or gvfs as root.

Comment: sorry @DanielT i read the other way round. You were suggesting of *not* using root. Shame on me. By being my user (uid: 1000) works. Thanks for help